# Abstract Error with JButton and Cannot Find Symbol on interface class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, abstract

I'm working on a simple Java GUI, but an error came out about abstract methods. I marked the codes that has an error with a comment ERROR - etc. The interface class is at the bottom, which also has an error about cannot find symbol. It is marked.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class KiloConverter extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;                   //To reference a panel
    private JLabel messageLabel;            //To reference a label
    private JTextField kiloTextField;       //To reference a text field
    private JButton calcButton;             //To reference a button
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 310;   //Window width
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 100;  //Window height

    public KiloConverter() {

        setTitle("Kilometer Converter");        //Set the window title
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);    //Set the size of the window

        //Specify what happens when the close button is clicked
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        buildPanel();                           //Build panel and add to frame
        add(panel);                             //Add panel to content pane
        setVisible(true);                       //Display the window
    }

    private void buildPanel() {

        messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter a distance in kilometers");
        kiloTextField = new JTextField(10);
        calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");

        //ERROR - method addActionListener in class AbstractButton cannot be   
        //applied to given types
        calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener()); 



        panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(messageLabel);
        panel.add(kiloTextField);
        panel.add(calcButton);
    }

    private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String input;
            double miles;

            input = kiloTextField.getText();
            miles = Double.parseDouble(input) * 0.6214;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input + "kilometers is " +
                    miles + " miles.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new KiloConverter();
    }
}
```

The interface class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public interface ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `java.awt.event.*` already calls it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public interface ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
}
```

Should be:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public interface ActionListener {

    //ERROR - Cannot find symbol
    //symbol: class Action Event
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
}
```

But now I look more closely at your example, you should not be declaring an interface with the exact same name as an existing interface!  This is more along the lines of what is required.

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public abstract class OurActionListener implements ActionListener {

    public abstract void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
}
```

Comment: And as an aside, you really should have figured out how to solve this type of error while coding command line apps.!

Comment: *"Doesn't `java.awt.event.*` already calls it?"*  Only in the source file where that is declared.

Comment: It seemed that fix the interface problem and the abstract error on the `CalcButtonListener` class. There's only 1 more error which is the `calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());`

Comment: I don't get what you meant about declaring an interface with the exact same name as an existing interface. Do you mean `ActionListener` is taken?

Comment: *"here's only 1 more error.."*  Yes, 'famous last words'.  Unless your question is answered by my latest edit, mark this as accepted and ask a new question.